# Flask and JQuery: How to load another page with JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I have a form where the user types in a search term:

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-val" placeholder="Search">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to get that user input and call a certaing page. For example `/index?search_term=foo`

I have tried doing it with JQuery with things like:

```js
$('#search-btn').on('click',function(){
    var search_term = $('#search-val').val();
    $.get( "/?search_term="+search_term);
});
```

On the Python side, I try to access the parameter like this:

```
s = request.args.get('search_term', '')
```

But it is not working. The page just refreshes and Python doesn't receive the `search_term`.
I am new to Flask so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to cancel the default action, which is to submit the page:

```
$('#search-btn').on('click',function(){
    var search_term = $('#search-val').val();
    $.get( "/?search_term="+search_term);
    return false;
});
```

Without the `return false` the browser will happily also submit the form itself, which in this case means it'll use `GET` on the same URL as the page (there is no `action` attribute). This in turn cancels any pending AJAX requests as well.

Of course, your `$.get()` call still doesn't do anything on the browser-side, but at least by cancelling the default form action, you get to see a server-side effect.

Comment: In addition, they're going to have to fix the `$.get()` which isn't doing anything as currently written.

Comment: @jfriend00: I was assuming that was a debug test; the OP isn't seeing anything happening on the Flask side.